# "Un bon courage" : ça se dit ?

Tags: usage, noms, langage-informel

J'ai entendu plusieurs personnes dire (ou écrire à leurs messages) "je vous souhaite un bon courage".
Peut-on dire *un bon courage* ? Je crois que non puisque que courage est un nom dénombrable.
Ai-je raison ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On s'attend probablement plus à quelque chose comme:

> Je vous souhaite bon courage.

> Je vous souhaite **du** courage.

> Je vous souhaite beaucoup **de** courage.

et peut-être que l'expression a été influencée par *je vous souhaite un bon weekend* mais *je vous souhaite un bon courage* n'est pas incorrect car courage peut très bien être aussi utilisé avec un article indéfini ou défini :

> Il a fait preuve d'**un** courage exceptionnel.

> Il a eu **le** courage d'y aller.

On trouve d'autres paires de ce type:

> Je vous souhaite **bon** appétit — Je vous souhaite **un bon** appétit

> Je vous souhaite **bon** voyage — Je vous souhaite **un bon** voyage

Comment: J'aurais aussi dit spontanément *je vous souhaite bon courage*, sans vraiment pouvoir expliquer pourquoi l'expression n'a pas d'article.

Comment: Ah c'est amusant, on peut souhaiter *une* bonne journée, *un* bon appétit, *le* bonjour mais on ne souhaite pas vraiment *un* bon courage.

Comment: @XouDo Pourquoi pas ? On trouve pas mal d'occurrences de *souhaiter un bon courage*.

Comment: @Greg C'est vrai. On trouve d'autres paires: *Je vous souhaite bon appétit / un bon appétit*, même chose avec *(un) bon voyage, (un) bon vent...*

Comment: Un peu comme souhaiter _un prompt rétablissement_. Peut-être que certains disent ça sans déterminant. Parfois on se demande si ce n'est pas souhaiter un « bon courage », la substantivation de l'interjection ?